# How to learn about website deployment, hosting and servers?

Tags: server, web-deployment, web-hosting

I am a beginner web developer. I have found that there are extensive resources for learning languages and frameworks, but I find my knowledge very lacking when it comes to website deployment, hosting, servers - basically all the things required to do after the website is complete on the local development environment.

It's not like there aren't resources for these things - there are, but they're usually very specific and advanced.

What are some good resources to learn this area (btw, what is it called?) of web development? Where to start?

Comment: Try searching for "How to host a website" on Google: http://www.w3schools.com/website/web_host_intro.asp

Comment: google is your best friend

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to simply dive in into the web hosting environment. At least, that's how I learned. Follow these general guidelines:-

1. If you're not conceptually aware of the technology behind web hosting, watch youtube/beginner videos to familiarize yourself with what's actually happening.
2. Sign up with a web hosting service. Godaddy and HostGator both have a very user-friendly interface.
3. If you'd like to go ahead and actually deploy your local website for free, try this site: http://www.domainsforauthors.com. This website is awesome and is absolutely free. You get a domain name, and plus hosting is free.
   For example, look at my sample website: http://spicelife.domainsforauthors.com
4. I will also list my college course page for web development resources:-
   http://cis3630.org/resources.html
5. Additionally, if you're more comfortable with local development methodologies, try free software like Microsoft Expression Web(Recommended) or Adobe Dreamweaver

Hope this helps you pal.

Also, as far as tutorials are concerned:-
https://www.thenewboston.com/
This guy, Bucky Roberts, is great. He has a lot of youtube videos for everything IT related.

Also, W3 schools always helps

Comment: domainsforauthors also provides a free online SQL database.